# how to automate the date change in a query using transact sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I work for a company where everyday I modify a query by changing the date of the day before, because the report is always from the previous day.
I want to automate the date change. I have made a table with two columns, one with all dates from this year and another with bits where if 0 is a working day and 1 if is a holiday.

I have successfully automated a little bit by telling if the day before is a working day then subtract 1 from the date (This is what happens everyday). But the problem is, that if is Monday appears as Friday, because Saturday and Sunday are not billable. And let's also say, that if today is Thursday and Wednesday and Tuesday we're holidays, then the report will run on Monday. I will leave you a picture, that shows how the table is made with dates.

**Remembering, that if there is no holidays in the middle of the week, always will be subtract one.**

[image: the image is not updated because I took it from a group]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this sort of thing is close to what you have done, but just extend it further. Create a BusinessDate table that has every date, and then every rule you have implemented inside it. You can go so far as to include a column such as `ReportDate` which will return,for every date, what date the report should be run for.

Do this once, and it will work forever more. You may have to update for future holidays once a year, but better than once a day!

It will also allow you to update things specific for your business, like quarter dates, company holidays, etc.

If you want to know more on the subject, look up topics around creating a date dimension in a data warehouse. Its the same general issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Too complicated for a comment and it involves a lot of guessing.

So everyday, your process starts by first determining if "today" is a work day. So you would do something like:

```
if exists (select * from <calendar> where date = cast (getdate() as date) and IsWorkday = 1")
begin
    <do stuff> 
end;
```

The "do stuff" section would then run a report or your query (or something that isn't very clear) using the most recent work day prior to the current date. You find that date using something like:

```
declare @targetdate date; 
set @targetdate = (select max(date) from <calendar> 
    where date < cast (getdate() as date) 
    and IsWorkday = 1); 

if @targetdate is not null 
   <run your query using @targetdate>
```

That can be condensed into less code but it is easier to understand when the logic is written step-by-step.